# How to increment a var everytime the year increases?

Tags: c#, increment

In my program I have a general price estimator for vehicles. If the year is below 1990, the price is set at 1000 dollars. But if the year is increased by one year for each year added there should be an additional 200 dollars added to the estimate. So for Example, if the year is 1991 then the price should be 1200 dollars.

I have tried to increment the Year in an if statement and add 200 to the variable used to set the price, which doesn't work. I also tried to use a for loop which wasn't successful either.

```
public decimal DetermineMarketValue()
        {
            decimal carValue;
            if (Year < 1990)
                carValue = 1000;
            if (Year > 1990)
                for (Year++)
                {
                    carValue += 200;     
                }

            return carValue;

        }
```

Each time the year increases by one the estimate should increase by 200 dollars.

Comment: You don't need a loop. That is a very basic math problem. 200 dollars per year over 1990. `carValue = 1000 + (Year - 1990) * 200`

Comment: As it stands, if the car was made in 1990 it has $0 value. Assuming it's $1,000 for 1990 and $200 for every year after 1990, `carValue = 1000 + (Year - 1990) * 200;`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have to use the loop, think you have to use a while loop instead of for:

```
public static decimal DetermineMarketValue(int Year)
        {
            decimal carValue = 1000;

            while (Year > 1990)
            {
                carValue += 200;
                Year--;
            }

            return carValue;

        }
```

Comment: Thank you this was the simplest solution to the problem. Not taking away from the other answers, they were also plausible.

Comment: @jGaines This is far from the simplest solution.  It is what you asked for but is the programming equivalent of using your fingers to count to 5.  The code in the comments you received are in fact simpler (one line) and have the advantage of being self explanatory.

Comment: This code has a serious flaw that ignores one of the question premises

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't initial the `carValue` the compiler will break up, however, you need to initial with a default value.

> In my opinion, don't use loops if you have a simple calculation like this.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DetermineMarketValue(2019));
    }

    public static double DetermineMarketValue(int Year)
    {
        double carValue = 1000;
        if (Year > 1990)
        {
            int numYears = Math.Abs(Year - 1990);
            carValue = 1000 + (numYears * 200);
        }
        return carValue;
    }
}
```

see the result [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AEHt1).

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted one, maybe I would declare int numYears outside the if clause and lose the brackets on (numYears*200), but it's far better then using a while loop for such a simple calculation.

Comment: the calculation can be as simple as this `1000 + (Math.Max(year, 1990) - 1990) * 200`

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the points raised in the comments but also I consider this is an academic exercise that is a good intro to looping logic so I'll persist with the looping solution. You're learning and seeminglynin the early stages - I can't stress enough he importance of writing out algorithms in English (or your native language) before trying to write code. All your life you've thought in English and now you're learning a new language with strict rules and a high requirement to be precise. Just as if you were speaking French, and you first assemble the sentence you want to say in English (with words in french order) then you translate to French, then you speak the French. It will take a long time before you THINK in French

Same for code; think English , write English comments, translate to c#, voila; nicely commented code (bonus points)

In my program I have a general price estimator for vehicles. If the year is below 1990, the price is set at 1000 dollars. But if the year is increased by one year for each year added there should be an additional 200 dollars added to the estimate. So for Example, if the year is 1991 then the price should be 1200 dollars.

I have tried to increment the Year in an if statement and add 200 to the variable used to set the price, which doesn't work. I also tried to use a for loop which wasn't successful either.

```
    //this should take in the year as a parameter to determine for 
    public int DetermineMarketValue(int forYear)
    {
        //pick 1000 as the starting value 
        int carValue = 1000;

        //if the user asked for earlier than 1990, quit early 
        if (forYear < 1990)
            return carValue;

        //they must have asked for a year after 1990, let's do the math 

        //start with 1990, test if we should add to the value, go up a year and test if we should add again
        //this logic starts with 1990 and if the user asked for 1990 the loop will not run, 1991 it UBS once etc
        //if the logic should be that a 1990 car is worth 1200, make it <= not <
        for (int year = 1990; year < forYear; year++)
        {
                //add 200 dollars onto the value and test
                carValue -= 200;     
        }

         //the loop has run the required number of times to get the final value, return it
        return carValue;

    }
```

**This code has a deliberate error** - I'm not here to do your degree for you, so I've made a blantant and deliberate mistake, partly to get you to think about the code written and partly to highlight how when you write your algorithm in comments you can check that the code matches the comments